# Global scope lost in vba-excel

Tags: vba, excel

Goal = create a variable that gets calculated when i start excel and have that variable globally available to all other modules -- i.e. the size of a given worksheet.

In ThisWorkbook i have this in the declaration part. I thought that each of these would be visible/persistent to other modules. This does actually get called as expected when i start excel.

```
Public BillingMaxRows As Integer
Public BillingMaxColumns As Integer
Public MonthlyMaxRows As Integer
Public MonthlyMaxColumns As Integer
```

and then this outside of the declarations part.

```
 Sub Workbook_Open()
    BillingMaxRows = Sheets("billing").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    BillingMaxColumns = Sheets("billing").UsedRange.Columns.Count
    MonthlyMaxRows = Sheets("Monthly Billings").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    MonthlyMaxColumns = Sheets("Monthly Billings").UsedRange.Columns.Count
    MsgBox (BillingMaxRows)    
End Sub
```

Then in a generic module i try `enter code here`and use any of these variables but they do not appear to be in scope.

Comment: I think your variables need to be in the top of a module not `ThisWorkbook`

Comment: ^^ or you would need to refer to them as `ThisWorkbook.BillingMaxRows` (for instance) outside of the `ThisWorkbook` code module.

Comment: Scott  - i tried moving the variables from the declarations area of ThisWorkbook to the declaration area of Module1...and they all are zero -- so even though they were calculated in ThisWorkbook those values are gone. So i don't think the first comment is correct

Comment: Yow...that suggestion did work...i.e. i can reference them as ThisWorkbook.BillingMaxColumns.

Comment: So basic question...when you declare a variable as Public in the declarations area do you always have to refer to it by <module>.variable vs. variable? I could see needing to do that if i had a local copy but in this case there was none

Comment: @Cooper5114 just tried it, I put in Module1, the declarations.  I put your code in ThisWorkbook, ran the code.  Then in Module2 I ran a single line sub `Debug.Print BillingMaxRows` and got the correct answer.  Not sure why you are getting 0.  But you should read what Matt says about using global declarations. It is not the best method.

Answer (score 3):

`ThisWorkbook`, as well as any `Worksheet` module, is an *object* - an instance of a *class module* - in this case an instance of the `Workbook` class.

`Public` members in class modules aren't *global*; they're publicly accessible to whoever is able to access an instance of the class.

So `Public Foo As Long` declared as a *field* in `ThisWorkbook`, would be accessible through:

```
Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Foo
```

And assigned all the same:

```
ThisWorkbook.Foo = 42
```

If you want the variable to be *publicly accessible*, but *read-only*, you must *encapsulate* it. Declare it `Private`, and expose a `Property Get` accessor for it:

```
Private mFoo As Long

Public Property Get Foo() As Long
    Foo = mFoo
End Property
```

And then you can have any member in `ThisWorkbook` assign `mFoo`, and any member in any other module of the project *read* `Foo`.

---

If you want an actual *global variable* (hint: you probably *don't*), then you need to declare it in a *standard module* (.bas) instead.

Comment: ok...understood and thanks. One related question. At what point does that instance of ThisWorkbook.Foo get destroyed? Reason i ask is that the first time i run the method that uses it...it has a value. When i hit a breakpoint and stop and then re-run the same method...then the value is gone.

Comment: `ThisWorkbook` is the workbook running the code.. It's destroyed when it's closed... Global state gets reset whenever the `End` keyword is encountered, or when you hit the debugger's Stop button - regardless of where it's stored (std module, global class instance, class default instance)

Comment: Also your values represent row numbers, and you're declaring them as 16-bit integers. Declare them `As Long` to avoid integer overflow issues.

Comment: That said the values should probably be exposed as get-only, calculated properties on the respective worksheet they're for. Aaand lastly, if that code means to find the last used cell with data, it's wrong. Research how to find the last used row in a worksheet, you'll find a highly-upvoted extremely detailed answer on this site.

Comment: Mat...thanks for each of the comments and i will search for how to determine the last used row/column...

Comment: ok...one more nube question as i hadn't done this in years...but how do i get the vb editor in excel to show much autocomplete. for example if i type

Comment: Sheets("foo"). <--i thought when i pressed "." i'd get prompted for choices

Comment: @Cooper5114 the `Sheets` collection doesn't only contain `Worksheet` objects; you should use the `Worksheets` collection if you're looking for a `Worksheet`, otherwise expect mayhem when you end up accidentally pulling a `Chart`! Anyway both collections yield `Variant/Object` items, so if you want *IntelliSense* and autocomplete, you need to assign the item to a local `Worksheet` object variable: `Dim sheet As Worksheet` and then `Set sheet = book.Worksheets(indexOrName)`. Any call made against `Object` can only be resolved at run-time (hence "late-bound") - careful then, it compiles typos!

Comment: got it...this is the problem w/getting started by creating macros and looking at the code they generate.